# Laravel Carbon seconds to forHumans

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with column seconds, where I insert online time (in seconds),

```
Carbon::parse($seconds)->forHumans();
```

Doesnt allow me to do this, there is a way to parse seconds and transfer it to humans reading? like 1 hour or 2 weeks?

Comment: echo Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5)->diffForHumans();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should return the result you're after:

```
Carbon::now()->subSeconds($seconds)->diffForHumans();
```

Comment: It is possible to remove after? an leave just minnutes, or days, weeks and etc

Comment: `str_replace('after', '',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds($this->onlinetime)->diffForHumans());`
Ok this worked

Comment: You can pass 'true' as the second parameter in diffForHumans to remove any modifiers like ago, from now etc. That way it also works for multi-lingual diffForHumans. So \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subSeconds($this->onlinetime)->dif‌​fForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::now(), true)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**Carbon Time in Human readable format**

```
// $sec will be the value from your seconds table
echo Carbon::now()->addSeconds($sec)->diffForHumans();
// OR
echo Carbon::now()->subSeconds($sec)->diffForHumans();
```

**Output**

```
// if $sec = 5
5 seconds from now
```

Found this useful doc [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff)

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**1) php artisan make:middleware LastActivityUser**

**2) Add this code in middleware  LastActivityUser**

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Cache;

class LastActivityUser
 {
     /**
     * The authentication factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
     protected $auth;

     /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
     public function __construct(Auth $auth)
     {
         $this->auth = $auth;
     }
     /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10);
            Cache::put('user-is-online-' . Auth::user()->id, true, $expiresAt);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**3) Add This Function in Your User Model**

```
public function is_online() {
        return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
    }
```

**4) Declare in (app\Http\Kernel.php)**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
   'web' => [

       \App\Http\Middleware\LastActivityUser::class, //Add this Line
   ]
```

**5) in Your Template Blade**

```
 @if($user->is_online())
   <span>On</span>
 @else 
   <span>Off</span>
 @endif
```